# How to check if my BroadcastReceiver receives the BOOT?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver who should receive the BOOT.

Is there a simple way to check if the BroadcastReceiver receives the BOOT correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming BOOT means BOOT_COMPLETED then you could use the following:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            //Do a Log or, less likely, a Toast or start your application here.
        }
    }
};
```

You would register this in the manifest like such:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.yourAppName.BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thank you very much. But I cannot make a Toast from a BroadcastReceiver (correct?), if I do a LOG Eclipse might simply miss it because the system is just rebooting, and I cannot launch any Activity becuase of the logic of my application. Please do you have any other idea? Thaank you very much anyway!!

Comment: You should have no problem with a Log. I can understand the Toast and Activity not working though. I am working on a non-standard industrial environment app that is a Home replacement and forget that it is not normal for the app to be the first and only activity after a reboot, but a Log should work just fine.